# Need to get wget output to log file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to run several commands in my batch.sh script (e.g. wget)

When I use

```
./batch.sh | tee logs.log
```

only my script output is written in logs.log but wget output is absent in logs.

How I can get all output (my script + output of scripts I call inside my script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the output you are interested is is printed to standard
error, rather than standard output. Alter your command like this:

```
./batch.sh 2>&1 | tee logs.log
```

This will cause both the standard and error streams of your script to
be piped into `tee`.

For more fine-grained control, you could give the `2>&1` treatment to
individual commands within your script.

In a way more specific to Wget, this option exists, and would allow
logging Wget's message to a separate file, for example:

```
-o logfile
--output-file=logfile
    Log all messages to logfile.  The messages are normally reported to
    standard error.
```